# why is my before_* keep triggering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this loop

```
 pages.each{|page| page.update_attribute(:sort_order, self.sort_order.to_i + 1)}
```

I used update_attribute to skip the before_update or before_save was not being called

```
before_save :set_data
before_update :set_data
```

but the set_data is being called again....any ideas on how to avoid this

I even tried the following

```
 pages.each do |page| 
   page.sort_order = self.sort_order.to_i + 1
   page.save(:validate => false)
 end
```

I am trying to update and the later pages to a sort_order + 1 so I can have the pages in some order

Any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs say that [`#update_attribute()`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attribute) and [`#save()`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save) invoke callbacks.

I had the same issue a few months ago and I don't think you can save a record without the callbacks being invoked.

### Edit

I just saw [`#update_column()`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_column) in the docs, which skips callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that `update_column` might do the trick

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
Page.where(:id => pages.collect(&:id)).update_all('sort_order=sort_order+1')
```

The advantage to this approach is you issue a single SQL query for an arbitrary number of rows. As a note, though, this will not alter the `sort_order` property of any models in memory.

This side-steps the entire callback chain. The documentation for [update_attribute](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attribute) says that validation is skipped, but callbacks *are* invoked.